# Is there any way to make single cream to double cream?

Tags: cream

Whipping cream is hard to find where I live in India. We have a dairy brand named "Amul" which sells cream of butterfat content of 25% and cannot be whipped! Whipping cream has about 35% fat content but its not available here. Can I add butter in it to increase the fat content needed for whipping, while stirring constantly for even distribution of fat?

Comment: I went with the close votes at first, but then I noticed that it is not an exact duplicate. The old question asks if adding butter will work, this one asks if there is any method at all.

Comment: Have you tried to evaporate some of the water in the cream, which might increase the fat percentage? Is this cream homogenized, or does it separate?

Comment: @JenniferS No I have not tried to evaporate the water in the cream, I never actually thought of that. Yes, the cream is homogenized.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34341/could-i-add-butter-to-single-cream-to-make-whipped-double-cream

Comment: @JenniferS evaporated milk is not the same thing as cream. It can be substituted in some cases, but it doesn't whip.

Comment: I understand that evaporated milk is not the same as cream.  I was meaning that if the user heated the cream and thus evaporated some of the water from the cream, it might make the fat percentage higher in the remains.  I don't know that it would work, but it might, after cooling, be whippable.

Comment: Amul does in fact sell a slightly thicker version of cream with 30% fat content - it has a red carton instead of the commonly-available blue one. Alas, if the fat content *has to be* greater than 35%, it's not enough either.

Answer (score 3):

Adding butter to cream will not work because you're not actually increasing the fat content of the cream-portion of your mixture. Cream is made up of microscope globules of butterfat surrounded by phospholipids (membranes of fatty acids that act as emulsifiers). This is what prevents the fat in the milk from congealing into a fatty mass (i.e. butter). The butter-making process breaks down these membranes and allows the butter to form. Butter is *also* a water-in-oil emulsion, but you can't re-emulsify it into cream by simply adding it back to a lower-fat cream base.

**An experimental solution**

*(This is highly experimental, so I'll remove it if someone says it doesn't work.)*

If you can only get 25% homogenized cream, try freezing and then thawing it. This should undo the homogenization to some degree, so it should separate when defrosted. Let the fat rise to the top, and pour off the excess cream (or drain off the whey from the bottom) to get the total milkfat content up into the "whipping cream" range.

*(This may not work. My concern is that this separate-by-freezing process won't actually give you whey + cream… for the same reason cream + butter won't work. The emulsion may be destroyed by the separate-by-freezing process. It may indeed create a higher-fat solution… but the resulting concoction may not be "whippable". Try it and report back. Thanks.)*

Comment: This method works, but the disclaimer is that the carton, the bowl, the whisk and everything else needed to work has to be refrigerated to be as cold as possible(but not frozen). It's also said that the whisking has to be done in an ice bath(well, that's a common factor - so let's ignore that one). It also takes longer to whisk - 10 to 15 minutes instead of 5 to 7 with 35%+ cream.

Answer (score 3):

I struggle with this answer, as it is very difficult to prove and document something is impossible.

However, there is no known good way to do this.   While there are some methods to substitute a butter/cream mixture for heavy cream, *they won't whip.*

Answer (score 3):

When cream is heated to between 115 degrees Farenheit and 145 degrees Farenheit, more fat becomes available to separate from the buttermilk. If you have a candy thermometer, I'd try slowly heating the cream to within this range, then cooling it so that the cream can separate from the buttermilk, then trying to use that to whip, as I suspect it will have a higher fat content to buttermilk ratio.

As well, double cream is made by putting cream into a centrifuge and forcing the buttermilk out through the physical action of separation. It's not making butter, but a step in between. So if you have access to a centrifuge (probably not I'd say?!) you could always try that....

Actually, forget what I just said - try this! It looks like you CAN add butter to milk to make whipping cream (but I'd use unsalted butter):
http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Heavy-Cream

Comment: This uses a mixture of 180ml whole milk and 75g butter. So it should result in a mixture of 76g fat in 255g of mixture - a 30% ratio. As the recipe indicates however - it's not whippable.

Comment: Also, don't do this for creamy products like ice cream. Someone tried it, and it was not smooth: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/112540/i-just-made-ice-cream-unfortunately-it-became-gritty-in-the-end-result-what-i?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Around fifty years ago we had a device that would make cream from unsalted butter and milk. It was a more modern version of [this](http://blog.modernmechanix.com/cream-maker-among-newest-home-aids/). I suspect that the result might not whip.

A quick look on ebay UK found an 'antique' one for sale. I'm not aware of any currently manufactured.