# How can I prevent little balls of oil in my ice cream when I'm using milk + butter instead of cream?

Tags: oil, ice-cream

So I found a substitute for cream and I used it in ice cream:

I put 14 oz of milk and 1/2 cup sugar and 1/3 cup butter and 2 caps vanilla extract heated it to get the water out it made a thicker milk and the ice cream was creamy but it has a little balls of oil from the butter that are not that great. If I can get them out that would be awesome.

Comment: Easy solution... use cream.

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/34341/67

Answer (score 1):

Adding butter to milk does not make it creamy. Your ice cream probably got a good enough consistency from the milk alone. That's not unusual, most commercial ice cream producers don't use cream either.

If you are asking what to do for the next batch: don't mix butter and milk, this is not just pointless, it leads to the fat globules you noticed. You can use cream for a richer ice cream, or milk if the creamless one is sufficient for you.

If you are asking what to do with this batch: The chances are not good. You can try melting it in the fridge, straining the ice cream base and churning it again. But the quality will be worse when churned for a second time, so I'm not sure it's worth the effort.